# Hooking up a concrete statue with umbrella to water for 'rain'

Tags: outdoor, plumbing-fixture

I have a statue with a smooth copper pipe coming out of bottom center. At the center above the umbrella is a fitting with holes (like a sprinkler on a watering can (except its about 1" diameter). I need to attach a fitting to the pipe at the bottom to run water to it so it looks like its raining. Pipe has no threads, it looks like someone cut it. Thanks!

Comment: A picture of what you need to connect water to will help greatly, as will any measurements as to the size.  Also it would be helpful if you told us what your source of water will be, ( hose,  pump, etc.)

Comment: @RMDman The pipe looks to be 1/4" id,or 3/8 od, and I want to hook it up to a hose outside.  I have pics but not sure how to add them.

Comment: To add pics: Click [edit], then find the "Sun & Mountain" icon above the text box - it'll walk you through adding the pics. Or, on a computer, just drag the images into the text box & it'll add them for you.

Comment: Normally this sort of thing is used as a centerpiece in a fountain where the water recirculates via a pump. If you are just going to hook it up to a hose, it will use a LOT of water, and it will make the area around itself very wet.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that you also have smooth copper pipe carrying water through the walls of your house. Your local hardware stores/plumbing suppliers/DIY centers are *filled* with a variety of bits that are designed to connect to smooth copper pipe to direct water where you want it to go.

Since I can't see what you see, I can only generally suggest:

- Make sure that the cut edge of the existing pipe is clean and square to the pipe.
- Make sure there are no rough edges inside or outside of the cut edge - these will cause leaks and/or damage connectors.
- Measure the outside of the pipe so you know what size fittings you need.
- Determine how you're going to get water to this statue.

  - Will you be running a garden hose to it?
  - Will it be permanently plumbed into your house's water supply?
- Purchase some fittings of the correct diameter to fit onto the pipe in the statue.

  - These can be solder on fittings, or the newer Sharkbite™<sup>*</sup> style push-to-connect fittings.
  - If you use a Sharkbite™, be *really* sure you've got a clean pipe end - roughness or bits of metal/dirt can damage the washers that make for a leak proof connection
- You can purchase straight or angled connectors with additional connections at the other end to get the pipe where you need it and in the condition you need it to connect it to the rest of the water supply.

  - You may want a 90° fitting to get the pipe "bent" to horizontal so you can run a garden hose to it. If so, you'll want a connector that has Garden Hose Thread on the other end, then you can just screw your hose to it. You may need some straight pipe to get the garden hose threaded end to a more convenient place.
  - You may want a straight fitting so you can connect it to a pipe coming out of the ground for a more permanent connection to the house water supply.
  - You may have some other set up - get the fittings you need to attach it to that setup. Fittings are available in a variety of standard angles: 22.5°, 45°, 90° and 180° (also known as straight). You can combine these in any way you need them to get to where you need to be.

You've given us a very vague problem definition, so all I can do is give a very broad idea of how to plumb this. This is very much similar to how you'd do any plumbing project: Know the pipe size and get the bits you need to get the water to where you want it.

<sup>*</sup>Note: Sharkbite is a brand name that's become synonymous with push-to-connect fittings the same way Kleenex™ is for facial tissue or Coke™ is for soda/pop, etc... Not an endorsement for any particular brand of push-to-connect fitting

Comment: Thanks, I got it! Yay!! You rock!!

Answer (score 2):

As commented, the typical application for such a statue is as a fountain or pond centerpiece, and the usual connection is to a pump, recirculating water from the basin or pond beneath the statue. Commonly that involves some rubber or vinyl tubing of an appropriate inside diameter to slip over the pipe's outside diameter, and a hose clamp or two to hold it in place. In your case 3/8" ID tubing.

Not using recirculation will result in using a **very large** amount of water, and turning the area around the statue into a swamp.

If you don't want a pool at the base of the statue, you can make a hidden pool filled with rocks or covered by pavers supported on pillars above the bottom of the pool so the water can drain through to be pumped up again.

Comment: Oooh... good points! I obviously missed that.